# JSON.Net and Linq

Tags: json, json.net

I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to linq and I'm working on a site that parses a json feed using json.net. The problem that I'm having is that I need to be able to pull multiple fields from the json feed and use them for a foreach block. The documentation for json.net only shows how to pull just one field. I've done a few variations after checking out the linq documentation, but I've not found anything that works best. Here's what I've got so far:

```
 WebResponse objResponse;
    WebRequest objRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
    objResponse = objRequest.GetResponse();
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        string json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        JObject rss = JObject.Parse(json);

        var postTitles =
            from p in rss["feedArray"].Children()
            select (string)p["item"], 
            //These are the fields I need to also query
            //(string)p["title"], (string)p["message"];

        //I've also tried this with console.write and labeling the field indicies for each pulled field
        foreach (var item in postTitles)
        {
            lbl_slides.Text += "<div class='slide'><div class='slide_inner'><div class='slide_box'><div class='slide_content'></div><!-- slide content --></div><!-- slide box --></div><div class='rotator_photo'><img src='" + item + "' alt='' /></div><!-- rotator photo --></div><!-- slide -->";
        }
    }
```

Has anyone seen how to pull multiple fields from a json feed and use them as part of a foreach block (or something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't you just reference the fields directly in your foreach loop, like this (below)?  I'm not sure you really need the linq query here.  (Note, I have cut out most of your html for this example for clarity.  You'll need to adjust for your actual project, do appropriate HTML escaping, etc.)

```
foreach (var p in rss["feedArray"].Children())
{
    lbl_slides.Text += string.Format(
        "<img src='{0}' title='{1}'/><span>{2}</span>",
        (string)p["item"],
        (string)p["title"],
        (string)p["message"]);
}
```

Same thing using linq would look like this:

```
var postTitles =
    from p in rss["feedArray"].Children()
    select new
    {
        Src = (string)p["item"],
        Title = (string)p["title"],
        Message = (string)p["message"],
    }

foreach (var item in postTitles)
{
    lbl_slides.Text += string.Format(
        "<img src='{0}' title='{1}'/><span>{2}</span>",
        item.Src, item.Title, item.Message);
}
```